# Finding a nonzero continuous function that satisfies this integral equation, but not unique?

Tags: integral-equations

If $h(x)$ is such that it satisfies 
$$
h(x) = \lambda \int_a^b K(x,y) h(y)\, dy
$$
Then for $\phi(x)$ a solution of 
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + \lambda \int_a^b K(x,y)\phi(y)\, dy
$$
it is true that $\phi + h$ is also a solution. But I am confused as to why this does not violate the uniqueness of solutions to these integral equations?

Comment: Why should uniqueness of solutions exist?

Comment: Do you know anything about the kernel $K$? If, for example, $\lambda K$ is always non-negative, then you can apply Gronwall's inequality to imply that $h$ is zero, I believe.